# WCF 3.5 Service and multiple http bindings

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I can't get my WCF service to work with more than one http binding.

In IIS 7 I have to bindings http:/service and http:/service.test both at 
port 80.

In my `web.config` I have added the baseAddressPrefixFilters but I can't add 
more than one

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix="http://service"/>
        <add prefix="http://service.test"/>
    </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

This gives almost the same error

> This collection already contains an  address with scheme http.  There
>   can be at most one address per scheme in  this collection.

as if no filers were specified at all (This collection already contains an 
address with scheme http. There can be at most one address per scheme in 
this collection. 
Parameter name: item)

If I add only one filter then the service works but only responds on the 
added filter address.

I've also tried with specifing multiple endpoints like (and only one filter):

```
<endpoint address="http://service.test" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IService" />
<endpoint address="http://service" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IService" />
```

Then still only the address also specified in the filter works and the other 
returns this error:

> Server Error in Application "ISPSERVICE" HTTP Error 400.0 
>   - Bad Request

Regards
Morten

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to deploy a WCF service to one of my web servers the other day and ran into a problem. I kept getting the following error message:

> This collection already contains an address with scheme http. There
>   can be at most one address per scheme in this collection.Parameter
>   name: item

The problem didn't happen on my local machine but did on the web server making it a little difficult to figure out what was causing it. It happened on the server because my web server is in a shared hosting environment in which case the WCF service also needs to know the host header. To do this I navigated to `<system.serviceModel>` in the web.config and added the following:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
<baseAddressPrefixFilters>    
    <add prefix=http://MyHostHeader />
</baseAddressPrefixFilters>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```